# How to to parse HTML contents of a page using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
url = 'https://www.trumba.com/calendars/smithsonian-events.xml'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open url)
```

I am trying to fetch the basic set of information like:

```
event_name
categories
sponsor
venue
event_location
cost
```

For example, for `event_name` I have this xpath:

```
"/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/h3/a/span"
```

And use it like:

```
puts doc.xpath "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/h3/a/span"
```

This returns nil for `event_name`.

If I save the URL contents locally then above XPath works.

Along with this, I need above mentioned information as well.  I checked the other XPaths too, but the result turns out to be blank.

Comment: You provide the url with pure xml. But to try find to find html in it. There is no any html in the document.

Comment: then how to extract the contents using nokogiri. @Aleksey

Comment: Don't use complete selectors like `"/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/h3/a/span"`. They're very error prone. Instead, find the shortest path to the desired node and use it. That way, if the document layout changes the selector will still function. As is, if the page changes a little the odds are good your code will break.

Comment: `event_name` doesn't exist in the XML document. Accuracy does count m'kay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided link contains XML, so your XPath expressions should work with XML structure.

The key thing is that the document has namespaces. As I understand all XPath expressions should keep that in mind and specify namespaces too.
In order to simply XPath expressions one can use the `remove_namespaces!` method:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
url = 'https://www.trumba.com/calendars/smithsonian-events.xml'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url)); nil # nil is used to avoid huge output

doc.remove_namespaces!; nil
event = doc.xpath('//feed/entry[1]') # it will give you the first event

event.xpath('./title').text # => "Conservation Clinics"
event.xpath('./categories').text # => "Demonstrations,Lectures & Discussions"
```

Most likely you would like to have array of all event hashes.
You can do it like:

```
doc.xpath('//feed/entry').reduce([]) do |memo, event|
  event_hash = {
    title: event.xpath('./title').text,
    categories: event.xpath('./categories').text
    # all other attributes you need ...
  }
  memo << event_hash
end
```

It will give you an array like:

```
[
  {:title=>"Conservation Clinics", :categories=>"Demonstrations,Lectures & Discussions"}, 
  {:title=>"Castle Highlights Tour", :categories=>"Gallery Talks & Tours"}, 
  ...
]
```

Comment: Removing the namespaces is only recommended when you are sure that the tags without the namespaces will not collide. Using CSS selectors is a more simple way of working with them and is covered in the documentation.  Read from http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces to the end of the page.

Comment: @theTinMan thank you for the comment. I didn't think CSS selectors have such power. I will try to update the answer after reading.

Comment: CSS are not as powerful as XPath, however they are usually much more readable, and, with the jQuery extensions that Nokogiri implemented, you can do quite a bit and still understand what the selector means at first glance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd go about doing this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('/Users/gferguson/smithsonian-events.xml'))
namespaces = doc.collect_namespaces

entries = doc.search('entry').map { |entry|
  entry_title = entry.at('title').text
  entry_time_start, entry_time_end = ['startTime', 'endTime'].map{ |p| 
    entry.at('gd|when', namespaces)[p]
  }
  entry_notes = entry.at('gc|notes', namespaces).text

  {
    title: entry_title,
    start_time: entry_time_start,
    end_time: entry_time_end,
    notes: entry_notes
  }

}
```

Which, when run, results in `entries` being an array of hashes:

```
require 'awesome_print'
ap entries [0, 3]

# >> [
# >>   [0] {
# >>     :title      => "Conservation Clinics",
# >>     :start_time => "2016-11-09T14:00:00Z",
# >>     :end_time   => "2016-11-09T17:00:00Z",
# >>     :notes      => "Have questions about the condition of a painting, frame, drawing,\n print, or object that you own? Our conservators are available by\n appointment to consult with you about the preservation of your art.\n \n To request an appointment or to learn more,\n e-mail DWRCLunder@si.edu and specify CLINIC in the subject line."
# >>   },
# >>   [1] {
# >>     :title      => "Castle Highlights Tour",
# >>     :start_time => "2016-11-09T14:00:00Z",
# >>     :end_time   => "2016-11-09T14:45:00Z",
# >>     :notes      => "Did you know that the Castle is the Smithsonian’s first and oldest building? Join us as one of our dynamic volunteer docents takes you on a tour to explore the highlights of the Smithsonian Castle. Come learn about the founding and early history of the Smithsonian; its original benefactor, James Smithson; and the incredible history and architecture of the Castle. Here is your opportunity to discover the treasured stories revealed within James Smithson's crypt, the Gre...
# >>   },
# >>   [2] {
# >>     :title      => "Exhibition Interpreters/Navigators (throughout the day)",
# >>     :start_time => "2016-11-09T15:00:00Z",
# >>     :end_time   => "2016-11-09T15:00:00Z",
# >>     :notes      => "Museum volunteer interpreters welcome visitors, answer questions, and help visitors navigate exhibitions. Interpreters may be stationed in several of the following exhibitions at various times throughout the day, subject to volunteer interpreter availability. <ul> \t<li><em>The David H. Koch Hall of Human Origins: What Does it Mean to be Human?</em></li> \t<li><em>The Sant Ocean Hall</em></li> </ul>"
# >>   }
# >> ]
```

I didn't try to gather the specific information you asked for because `event_name` doesn't exist and what you're doing is very generic and easily done once you understand a few rules.

XML is generally very repetitive because it represents tables of data. The "cells" of the table might vary but there's repetition you can use to help you. In this code

```
doc.search('entry')
```

loops over the `<entry>` nodes. Then it's easy to look inside them to find the information needed.

The XML uses namespaces to help avoid tag-name collisions. At first those seem really hard, but Nokogiri provides the `collect_namespaces` method for the document that returns a hash of all namespaces in the document. If you're looking for a namespaces-tag, pass that hash as the second parameter.

Nokogiri allows us to use XPath and CSS for selectors. I almost always go with CSS for readability. `ns|tag` is the format to tell Nokogiri to use a CSS-based namespaced tag. Again, pass it the hash of namespaces in the document and Nokogiri will do the rest.

If you're familiar with working with Nokogiri you'll see the above code is very similar to normal code used to pull the content of `<td>` cells inside `<tr>` rows in an HTML `<table>`.

You should be able to modify that code to gather the data you need without risking namespace collisions.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer. I was struggling with namespaces when I tried to update my answer.